# solve $\log(-0.7x-9)=1+5\log(5)$. I get $370$ whereas textbook solution says $-44655.7143$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'm to solve $\log(-0.7x-9)=1+5\log(5)$ using a calculator. I arrived at $370$ when I'm told the solution is $-44655.7143$.

My working:

$$\log(-0.7x-9)=1+5\log(5)$$
$$\log(-0.7x-9)=1+\log(25)$$
$$\log(-0.7x-9)=\log(25)+\log(10)$$
$$\log(-0.7x-9)=\log(250)$$
$$-0.7x-9=250$$
$$-0.7x=259$$
$$x=\frac{259}{0.7}$$
$$x=370$$

Where did I go wrong, and how can I arrive at $-44655.7143$?

Comment: The answer is clearly not $370$....after all, $-.7\times 370-9<0$ so the left hand isn't even defined at $370$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors in your calculations. First, $5^5 \ne 25$...And in the third line before the end you are missing a sign. It should be, using your steps,
$$\log(-0.7x-9)=1+5\log(5)$$
$$\log(-0.7x-9)=1+\log(3125)$$
$$\log(-0.7x-9)=\log(3125)+\log(10)$$
$$\log(-0.7x-9)=\log(31250)$$
$$-0.7x-9=31250$$
$$-0.7x=31259$$
$$x=-\frac{31259}{0.7}$$
$$x\approx - 44655.7 $$